# How can I find a second property with a duplicate name from a dynamic object?

Tags: dapper

Using [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) I have a result set which contains two SQL columns with the same name. How do I read the values?

Both the `User` and `Skill` table have a column called `Name`.

An example of my code:

```
var query = _connection.Query(@"
    select u.*, s.* 
    from [User] u 
    left join Skill s ON s.UserID = u.UserID
    where Username=@Username", 
    new { Username }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There won't be two `name` properties. In my short investigation the result contained the first name but I'm sure this is not guaranteed.

To get both `name`'s you will need to alias one or both columns in your sql:

```cs
var query = _connection.Query(@"
    select u.name as user_name, s.name as skill_name 
    from [User] u 
    left join Skill s ON s.UserID = u.UserID
    where Username=@Username", 
    new { Username }
);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I gave up on dapper for the time being. Using alias will solve my issue so I'll accept your answer.